# TreeMap.higherEntry returns an unexpected null

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, nullpointerexception, null

Okay, so I have this piece of code that is supposed to get a random entry from a weighted list. However, when I try to call TreeMap.higherEntry, it returns null even though there is a higher entry available. lowerEntry does work, ceilingEntry returns the same null. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Randomizer<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    private Random rng;
    private double defaultWeight;
    public Randomizer(List<E> list) {
        super(list);
        rng = new Random();
        defaultWeight = 1.0d;
    }
    /*Stripped some uninteresting constructor variations for clarity*/
    public void setSeed(long seed) {
        rng.setSeed(seed);
    }
    public E getRandom() {
        TreeMap<Double,E> map = new TreeMap<>();
        double total = 0;
        for(E e : this) {
            if(e instanceof Weighted) {
                map.put(((Weighted) e).getWeight(),e);
                total += ((Weighted) e).getWeight();
            } else {
                map.put(defaultWeight,e);
                total += defaultWeight;
            }
            System.out.println(total);
        }
        double value = rng.nextDouble() * total;
        System.out.println(value + ", " + map.higherKey(value));
        return map.higherEntry(value).getValue();
    }
}
```

And here is the console output of a small dataset:

```
5.0
9.0
11.0
14.0
15.0
15.5
19.5
22.5
24.0
26.5
27.5
28.0
9.987466924354226, null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at me.datafox.utils.Randomizer.getRandom(Randomizer.java:52)
    at me.datafox.grick.SwordTest.main(SwordTest.java:39)
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? The dataset is formatted in a very weird way so I'm leaving it out but it should be apparent that calculating the total from the weight list is not the problem I'm facing.

Comment: `it returns null even though there is a higher entry available`? Are you sure there's a higher entry available? You can simply print `map` and `value` before calling `map.higherKey(value)` and see for yourself.

Comment: Considering the output no single value seems to be larger than 5. So the map doesn't contain any key higher than 9.

Comment: There is no higher entry as it seems. Have a look at the values you're printing: `System.out.println(total);` - that's the total of the values added as per `total += ((Weighted) e).getWeight();` If you have a look at the totals printend, the highest value that has been added should be 5.0

Comment: You print total to console instead of the value you add. As you can see on your cumulative total value there are no values added higher than 9.987466924354226. The highest value is 5.0.

Comment: @Eran And now I feel like a major idiot. After four hours of sleep the simplest things kinda miss your radar.

Comment: Check my comment

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#higherEntry-K-) says:

> Returns a key-value mapping associated with the least key strictly greater than the given key, or null if there is no such key.

Your code does:

```
double value = rng.nextDouble() * total;
```

Long story short: the only explanation is that there is no such value meeting that criteria. In other words: your logic is fundamentally broken here.

The point is: you are multiplying a **random** value. All bets are off here. Sometimes your code might result in a non-null result, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question to close this thread. My problem was here:

```
map.put(((Weighted) e).getWeight(),e);
total += ((Weighted) e).getWeight();
```

The map was supposed to be a map where each key was larger than the previous, but due to lack of sleep I just added the original weights to the map. Here's a fixed piece of code:

```
total += ((Weighted) e).getWeight();
map.put(total,e);
```

Comment: That is not the proper way to "close" a thread. You accept the answer that answered your problem. If one of the answer inspired your change ... then comment on it, and have the person writing the answer update that input, then accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // creating tree map 
  TreeMap<Integer, String> treemap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

  // populating tree map
  treemap.put(2, "two");
  treemap.put(1, "one");
  treemap.put(3, "three");
  treemap.put(6, "six");
  treemap.put(5, "five");

  // getting higher key for key 4          
  System.out.println("Checking values of the map");
  System.out.println("Value is: "+ treemap.higherKey(3));
}
```

***The output of this is 5***

Your code is doing this:

***11 -> getHigherKey = 5***

***9 -> getHigherKey = null***

Comment: I don't get your last 2 lines, what are 11 and 9?

Answer (score 0):

The key for your map should be the value of `total`, not the individual weights.

```
    double total = 0;
    for (E e : this) {
        if (e instanceof Weighted) {
            total += ((Weighted) e).getWeight();
        } else {
            total += defaultWeight;
        }
        map.put(total, e);
        System.out.println(total);
    }
    double value = rng.nextDouble() * total;
    double result = map.higherKey(value);
    System.out.println(value + ", " + result);
    return result.getValue();
```

For example if you have entries A, B, C with weights 4, 2, 5 respectively, you want to have keys 4, 6, 11. That way A covers 0-4, B covers 5-6 and C covers 7-11. I hope that explains it sufficiently.